# Retrieving Brithdays as date format from varChar column

Tags: php, mysql, date, varchar

```
$bugun = date("Y-m-d");
$dogum_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM secim_uyeleri WHERE STR_TO_DATE(uye_dogum,'%d-%m-%Y') = '".$bugun."'");
           while ($a= mysql_fetch_array($dogum_cek)){
           $uye_dogum = $a['uye_dogum'];
           $uye_isim = $a['uye_isim'];
           $uye_tel = $a['uye_tel'];


             echo' 
                <tr>
                <td>'.$uye_isim.'</td>
                <td>'.$uye_tel.'</td>
                <td>'.$uye_dogum.'</td>
            </tr>';}
```

I have varChar column in mysql table where i keep birthdays.(I inserted as varChar because of excel including.) So now i have to retrieve rows with current days who has birthdays. I tried str_to_date to retrieve varChar as date but could not get any results.

"uye_dogum" is the varChar column where i keep birthdays as dd-mm-YYYY.

```
SELECT * FROM secim_uyeleri WHERE ( I NEED THIS PART) = '".$bugun."'
```

Comment: Sorry - but OK - the `mysql_*` extension is obsolete. Error suppression is **always** a bad idea. **Never** store dates in a VARCHAR as you can't use DATE query functions on them (MySQL has a DATE type)... essentially, from where you're at, you might be best starting over.

Comment: I am going to use mysqli in host ofcourse just i wanted to learn if i can retrieve varChar as date.. Cuase there are more than 8000 rows inserted and can't change them. Maybe i can retrieve first 5 characters of column (dd-mm) and make the query according to this?

Comment: You'll regret it in the long run, but if you want to do a partial match on `d-m` against `d-m-Y` you could just use `LIKE`... `"SELECT * FROM secim_uyeleri WHERE uye_dogum LIKE '" . $bugun . "%'"` ... it's all very format specific though.

Comment: This will be just for some days so i think i will try to use LIKE as you said.. Thanks..

Comment: Please reformat your question, and add a code example of what you have already tried - e.g. str_to_date()

Comment: I updated the codes as i used. With this query i can retrieve exact days but as you know for birthdays i should not use year part..

Answer (score 0):

```
$bugun = date("d-m");
$dogum_cek = mysql_query("SELECT uye_dogum,uye_isim,uye_tel FROM secim_uyeleri WHERE LEFT(uye_dogum,5) LIKE '".$bugun."' ORDER BY uye_isim");
           while ($a= mysql_fetch_array($dogum_cek)){
           $uye_dogum = $a['uye_dogum'];
           $uye_isim = $a['uye_isim'];
           $uye_tel = $a['uye_tel'];


             echo' 
                <tr>
                <td>'.$uye_isim.'</td>
                <td>'.$uye_tel.'</td>
                <td>'.$uye_dogum.'</td>
            </tr>';}
```

Solution is here.. i can get all rows like this.. For little solution i am going to use it..